# Entity Framework 1 to Many creates new objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework for my Microsoft Sql Data Base.
First entity is **Product**:

```
 public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        ProductStories = new HashSet<ProductStory>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public HashSet<ProductStory> ProductStories { get; set; }
}
```

And another entity is **ProductStory**, which stores story about income or outcome of **Products**.

```
public class ProductStory
{
    public int ProductStoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product.Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

     public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

So one **Product** could be in mane **ProductStories**, or in none.

I will not show all code(too big), so when I firstly create a single **Product** instance and save it in DB. Then I create a single **ProductStory** and reference to property Product to that instance of Product.
Then I save this **ProductStory**, there becomes 2 instances of **ProductStory**.
As I read, and I made this as virtual property:

```
public virtual Product.Product Product { get; set; }
```

How this problem could be solved?

I'm using `EntityTypeConfiguration` for tables configuration.

```
public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
    {
        public ProductMap()
        {
            ToTable("Products").HasKey(x => x.ProductId);

            Property(x => x.ProductId).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255).HasColumnName("Name");
                //.HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Name") { IsUnique = true }));
            Property(x => x.Description).IsOptional().HasColumnName("Description");
            Property(x => x.Deleted).HasColumnName("Deleted");
        }
    }
```

And for ProductStory:

```
class ProductStoryMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductStory>
    {
        public ProductStoryMap()
        {
            ToTable("ProductStories").HasKey(ps => ps.ProductStoryId);

            Property(ps => ps.ProductStoryId).IsRequired();
            //Property(ps => ps.ProductId).IsRequired().HasColumnName("ProductId");

            Property(ps => ps.Count).HasColumnName("Count");
            Property(ps => ps.DateTime).HasColumnName("DateTime");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are showing twice the code for ProductStory and never the code for Product. Also, your ProductStory is missing a ProductId to store the reference of Product

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Your ProductStoryMap needs a ForeignKey to Product now

Comment: I added this into `ProductStoryMap` :
`HasOptional<Product>(ps => ps.Product).WithMany(p => p.ProductStories).HasForeignKey(ps => ps.ProductId);`

But it starts crushing with exceptions on recreating database.

Comment: You will need to post the exception details then. Also, it should be HasRequired, unless for some reason you can have a ProductStory that does not have a Product

Comment: Please show the code how you try to insert a `ProductStory`

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code:

```
//Change this:
public HashSet<ProductStory> ProductStories { get; set; }
//For this (virtual is needed here, also use ICollection rather than any specific implementation)
public virtual ICollection<ProductStory> ProductStories { get; set; }

//Change this:
public virtual Product.Product Product { get; set; }
//For this (virtual makes no sense here)
public Product.Product Product { get; set; }
```

And lastly, `ProductStory` needs a way to keep the reference to its parent `Product`. This is what creates the Foreign Key relationship in your database and allows Entity Framework to link the tables. So add this to `ProductStory`:

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

If you are still getting a duplicated object (which may happen), ensure you are setting the `ProductId` to the `ProductStory` you are saving.

Comment: As I understand, I have to forse 
'productStory.ProductId = product.ProductId';
in code, right?

Comment: I did as you said, but it still makes copies.

Comment: @KamikyIT did you recreate/update the database so that it has a foreign key between product and product story?

Comment: Yes, I deleted whole DataBase, and it's recreated when I run code.
Btw, I'm using `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` to configure my DataBase tables.
I will add them into my post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was about Entity Framework "bug/feature".
As I add new `ProductStory` into DataBase, it attaches the whole graph(including all other entities references and **recreates** them).
So before commiting new `ProductStory`, I have to set to null all it's navigation properties to avoid recreating.

Comment: So basically the solution is out of scope for the code that you posted in your question, right?

Comment: @grek40 50/50. Camilo Terevinto helped about `HasRequired()` in `EntityTypeConfiguration`.
The other problem was as I wrote upper.